# Assert Throws Error in MarkLogic Unit Test for JavaScript Function with Parameters

Tags: unit-testing, marklogic

The `test:assert-throws-error` function in MarkLogic Unit Test framework supports the anonymous function pattern to test a XQuery function with parameters:

```
test:assert-throws-error(function() {fn:concat("this", "that")})
```

Ref: https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-unit-test/issues/111

But I am not sure how to do the same for JavaScript function:

```
assertThrowsError(() => 'this' + 'that')
```

would lead to the following error:

> XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) $function as xdmp:function -- Invalid coercion: function (), "/test/suites/my/test.sjs" as xdmp:function

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is one of those cases where XQuery and JavaScript don't mesh perfectly. The library is expecting an `xdmp:function`, but it's getting JavaScript function. Something to try: put your function in a library, then use `xdmp.function` to get a reference to the JS function instead of the more direct way. (Not ideal, but I think an update to the framework function would be required for what you're doing.)

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Hopefully support for JS function will arrive in an upcoming release soon.

Comment: https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-unit-test/issues/123